# Javascript convert a string to number

Tags: javascript, string, numbers, exponent

I have a string of value

```
1.02947826525E9
```

and it has exponential component. I want to convert this string to corresponding numeric value.

Is there a direct way to convert this string to numeric value?

Answer (score 3):

Use the built-in [`parseFloat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat).

```
parseFloat('1.02947826525E9')
```

Answer (score 2):

**Using `parseFloat()`:**

```js
console.log(parseFloat('1.02947826525E9'))
```

**USING `Number()`**

```js
console.log(Number('1.02947826525E9'));
```

**USING Explicit type conversion**

```js
console.log('1.02947826525E9' * 1);
```